# JS code works from console, doesn't work as normal web code

Tags: javascript, html

HTML code:

```
<div class="color-box yellow left margin-right" id="yellow-box">Yellow</div>
<div class="color-box black left margin-right" id="black-box">Black</div>     
<div class="color-box green left margin-right" id="green-box">Green</div>
<div class="color-box orange left margin-right" id="orange-box">Orange</div>
<div class="color-box red left margin-right" id="red-box">Red</div>
```

JS code:

```
function addListeners()
    var colorList = document.getElementsByClassName('color-box');
    for (var i=0; i<colorList.length; i++){
        colorList[i].addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    }
}
```

The other functions that I evoked (mouseDown, mouseUp) don't matter for the matter.
The code above works in console but as normal web code, the function doesn't even go into the for loop since colorList's length is 0.

I tried debugging the aforementioned code using `console.log()` and came to the conclusion that `colorList[0]` returns the first node in console, but in normal web code it is undefined.

I tried to search for my question in other queries, but I couldn't understand them since I am not much of a seasoned programmer myself. From what I did make out, those programmers had semi-colons missing, et cetera.

Comment: Are you sure your document actually contains these `div`s with said class, and they are properly closed and nested and contained within a `<html><body>` structure? From what I can see, your javascript is good (as proven by the fact that it works in a console)

Comment: Are you sure that the DOM is already loaded at the point of time when your function `addListeners` is executed? In the console, this is obviously the case. But in the web page, the DOM will not be available before the event `DOMContentLoaded` is fired.

Answer (score 4):

Try to write your js code at the end of your body tag

```
<script>
 //your code
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you can write it on window.onload event

```
function addListeners() {
  var colorList = document.getElementsByClassName('color-box');
  for (var i=0; i<colorList.length; i++){
    colorList[i].addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
  }
}
window.onload = function(){addListeners()}
```

This will call the function only when window is properly loaded.